# How does a collator or validator choose their signing key?

Tags: grandpa, babe, collator, validator, aura

If I were to insert multiple (valid) author keys over RPC, how does a collator or validator choose which key to sign with when producing a block? As far as I know this cannot be set on start-up.

Comment: It's generally not recommended to do this, because certain parts of the validator code don't handle 'validator virtualization' well. But as Joe says, nodes will just search for keys that they control within the active validator public keys recognized by the chain at any point in time.

Answer (score 3):

This is what `session.set_keys` achieves, it declares that an on-chain account (presumably with keys in some form of cold storage) will sign blocks/consensus messages with some other key. When a node starts, it checks the chain state to see if any private keys in its keystore match the public keys that are registered on-chain. If it has the keys, then it will sign the corresponding messages with them.